# AngularJS: single page app demo not working

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

i'm having this online course on AngularJS, which provides the code in folders, according to the lesson. This one is about routing and single page applications; similar demos and structures work on plunker (like this [one](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating) ) but not in my machine...I don't understand why, can someone help me out?

EDIT: actually, if I download this [demo](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating) the thing wont work...

INDEX file:

```
<html lang="en-us" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <style>
            html, body, input, select, textarea
            {
                font-size: 1.05em;
            }
        </style>


        <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">AngularJS</a>
                </div>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/second"><i></i> Second</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div class="container">

            <div ng-view></div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

The Module file: APP.JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/main.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

    .when('/second', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/second.html',
        controller: 'secondController'
    })

    .when('/second/:num', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/second.html',
        controller: 'secondController'
    })

});

myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {

    $scope.name = 'Main';

}]);

myApp.controller('secondController', ['$scope', '$log', '$routeParams', function($scope, $log, $routeParams) {

    $scope.num = $routeParams.num || 1;

}]);
```

Pages one and two (views):

```
<h1>This is Main.</h1>
<h3>Scope value: {{ name }}</h3>

<h1>This is second.</h1>
<h3>Scope route value (on second page): {{ num }}</h3>
```

The folder structure. The code is as suggested 
[image]

Comment: Your references for angular is correct?

Comment: Are u getting any error in console

Comment: well, yes, it says "angular is not defined" first line on app.js

Comment: I dont get it because I have other samples - not about routing - and they work....

Comment: Do they have the same script source as above? Try changing the script tags as below

Comment: Try changing it to index.html and what is the url for your website?

Answer (score 1):

Your references for angular and bootstrap are not correct

**Angularjs**

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

**Bootstrap**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Comment: Bootstrap now loads, but the links dont work. Here's the log:`Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/$compile/tpload?p0=pages%2Fmain.html
    at angular.js:38
    at g (angular.js:14932)
    at angular.js:12076
    at m.$eval (angular.js:13276)
    at m.$digest (angular.js:13088)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:13380)
    at HTMLHtmlElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:10414)
    at HTMLHtmlElement.c (angular.js:2977)`

Comment: It is telling that it failed to fetch the templates that u have defined in your routing. Are the paths correct?

Comment: I guess so, I haven't changed the file structure. Besides, as I said above, if I build a simple module and controller (two files), the thing works fine, so I guess the problem isnt the CDN

Comment: Do you have the html files in pages directory which is in the same level as your app.js?

Comment: yes, I'm sorry, for the late reply. The folder was supose to work as it is; changing the links only gave me bootstrap...As for Angular, if i write some basic code like an object attached to scope and then render it, the thing works...so i'm confused

Comment: The above things will work as it does not have anything to do with routing. But now since you have introduced routing, you have to do it the correct way. Did you declare the above html files?

Comment: I have posted a pic of the structure. The links are as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct you urls like this

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/main.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

    .when('/second', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/second.html',
        controller: 'secondController'
    })

    .when('/second/:num', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/second.html',
        controller: 'secondController'
    })

});

myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {

    $scope.name = 'Main';

}]);

myApp.controller('secondController', ['$scope', '$log', '$routeParams', function($scope, $log, $routeParams) {

    $scope.num = $routeParams.num || 1;

}]);
```

```html
<html lang="en-us" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <style>
            html, body, input, select, textarea
            {
                font-size: 1.05em;
            }
        </style>


        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">AngularJS</a>
                </div>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/second"><i></i> Second</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div class="container">

            <div ng-view></div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Also you need to add a page for the view on the following path in project pages/main.html

[image]

Comment: ? honnestly I don't understand you answer. The code and structure are exacly the same...

Comment: I have added https in all links you have used in your header

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your application throught the localhost like this:

[image]

Just mount your project on HTTP server.

```
$> sudo npm -g live-server
$> cd path/to/root/dir/project
$> live-server
```

EDIT: and eventually, include every time your scripts at bottom of body:

```
<body>

    .....
    .....
    .....

    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```